# Keep running the function without restarting it?

Tags: ros, c++, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this problem that i cannot make run my while(true) without it get restarted..

I think the problem occurs since

in my main loop

```
int main
{
    ros::init(argc,argv, "loop");
    loop();
    ros::spin();
}
```

In side loop()

```
void loop()
{
   
   cout << "Are you ready" << endl;
   while(ready == false
  {

      //DO SOMETHING 
     ros::spinOnce() //needed since i read from a subscriber in this while loop
  }

 cout << "i am out" << endl;
 while(true)
 {
 //do something again
     ros::spinOnce();
  }

}
```

Right now it keep printing "are you ready", the idea was it should print it once.. I don't understand how it comes outside the loop.. it seems impossible to do..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205413/keep-running-the-function-without-restarting-it?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This code snippet should not produce the output you describe.
Maybe you omitted the line which causes your problem. Can you post a more complete code? (e.g. in the line `while(ready == false` a bracket is missing)

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0